# Gridview sorting when Header text changed in RowDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView on my webpage whose DataSource is a DataTable which is populated at runtime. AllowSorting property of GridView is True. I have successfully implemented manual sorting for this GridView.

But I had to translate the webpage to other languages for which I used local resource files. I changed the Header text of GridView columns in RowDataBound event. Since then I'm unable to sort the GridView.

```
       protected void GVSummaryTable_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells.Count > 0)
    {
        //Translate header text
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = GetLocalResourceObject("GVSummaryTableName").ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = GetLocalResourceObject("GVSummaryTableLoginLevel").ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = GetLocalResourceObject("GVSummaryTableLoginID").ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = GetLocalResourceObject("GVSummaryTableDate").ToString();

        }

    }

}
```

What should I do to enable sorting for the columns? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing the code to below solved the problem:

```
          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) 
        { 
            LinkButton LnkHeaderText = e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as LinkButton; 
            LnkHeaderText.Text = "Name"; 
        }
```

Comment: what is the reason we need to change it to a link button

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the problem is related to the Header text since the sorting is normally done with the **Sort Expression**. Please, make sure you are also giving a value to this property when doing the Sorting. Hope this helps!

Comment: at run time the header will change itself to a link button when a sort expression attribute is added. but when we change the header text dynamically it changes into a text, so we have to dynamically change it to a link button too